# What is this simple function called?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, monad-transformers, state-monad

Have you already seen the following function? What is it called? What is it useful for? can it be defined more generically than just for `StateT`?

```
simpleFunction (StateT f) = StateT $ (\s -> return (f s, s))
```

By the way, ghc gives it the type `Monad n => StateT s m a -> StateT s n (m (a, s))`.

And there is an alternative definition:

```
simpleFunction m = do
  s <- get
  mapStateT (\l -> return (l, s)) m
```

Comment: I suspect this can be defined more generically than just for `State`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Good point. Do you have a proposal for such generic definition? I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Is this a homework question ;-? I'm asking because if it is one there is (probably) a (somewhat easy) answer. If it isn't, I'm not sure if there is an answer to this.

Comment: @UliKöhler: This is definitely not a homework question ;-!

Comment: can you motivate the question - can you show an example of how you want to use this function.

Comment: @d8d0d65b3f7cf42: No I cannot. I just find this function handsome.

Comment: I don’t think this function is very deep. It just takes the current state, but otherwise `f s :: m (a, s)` is quite independent of the remaining `StateT s n` computation.

Answer (score 1):

Having two monads like `n (m a)` isn't usually very useful (the composition might not be a monad etc.). So I guess more usable version would be of type
`(Monad m) => StateT s m a -> StateT s m (a, s)`.

This can be generalized to an arbitrary state transformer over `m`:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.State

f1 :: (MonadState s (t m), MonadTrans t, Monad m) => StateT s m a -> t m (a, s)
f1 (StateT f) = get >>= lift . f
```

And since the only thing we need is `get`, we can further generalize to:

```
f2 :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m, Monad (t m)) => t m s -> StateT s m a -> t m (a, s)
f2 g (StateT f) = g >>= lift . f
```

If you really need to have two monads, perhaps [`MFunctor`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph-1.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Morph.html#t:MFunctor) would be useful - functions like `hoist` or [`generalize`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph-1.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Morph.html#v:generalize) allow to switch between monads.

Answer (score 0):

The simpleFunction structure is parameterized over two things: a StateT monad and a function f. As it is shown in both given definitions, the simpleFunction gets the state from the internals of the monad, then map both the return value and final state of a computation using a given function.

Following a very simple example to see a working example:

```
import Control.Monad.State

inc :: State Int Int
inc = do
    n <- get
    put (n + 1)
    return n

simpleFunction = do
                s <- get
                mapState (\l -> (l,s)) inc

main = do
    print $ runState simpleFunction 1
```

The result is: ((1,2),1) which is the ((return value,final state),initial state)

The simpleFunction as you see is not complicated. It can be used with monads other than StateT. In this case, you have to implement your own map and get.

Hope it's useful!